# How to manipulate components of pathnames in Tcl?

Tags: path, tcl

I'm writing a reporting script that's part of a portable testing package. The user can unzip the package anywhere on their system, which is fine, but it means I can't hardcode a path.

Let's say that on my system, this script lives at C:/projects/testpackage/foo/bar/script.tcl. I need to set a variable, packageLocation, the path to /testpackage. In this example, it would be C:/Projects/testpackage. But when the user gets the package, he or she could put it anywhere, like so:

C:/Users/whatever/testpackage.

So, **how can I call two levels up from the location of my currently running script?** In Batch, I could do

```
    :: example.bat
    cd %~dp0
    cd ../..
    set packageLocation=%cd%
```

In Tcl, I'm lost. I know that the current location of the running script can be called as $::argv0. I've tried using cd ../.., but to no avail. It tries to set packageLocation as "../..C:/Projects/testpackage/foo/bar/script.tcl."

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set where [file normalize [file dirname [info script]]]
set parts [file split $where]
set pkgloc [file join {*}[lrange $parts 0 end-2]]
```

Should do what you want.

It goes like this:

1. Obtains the directory name of the file from which the current script was read to be evaluated, then normalizes it (replaces `~`, `..` etc).
2. Splits obtained full pathname at path separators producing a list of path components.
3. Extracts a new list from the list of path components containing all them from the beginning except the last two, then joins them back to produce the final name.

---

If you have Tcl < 8.5, the last line will have to be rewritten:

```
set last [expr {[llength $parts] - 3}]
set pkgloc [eval [list file join] [lrange $parts 0 $last]]
```